# How to Join 4 table based on bridge id and get the data and display in sql

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to join 4 table (I'm passing the POST bridge_id)  based on bridge id and display the data, I have tried this query i'm getting the issue below the my code is there please check my code what i have to did mistake please help...

Query :

```
 $query = "select inventory_details.bridge_id,inventory_details.status, inventory_details.inventory_review,inventory_details.transaction_datetime,
                        inspection_details.status,inspection_details.transaction_datetime,inspection_details.inspection_review,
                        testing_details.status,testing_details.transaction_datetime,testing_details.testing_review,    
                        repair_details. status,repair_details. transaction_datetime,repair_details. repair_review  
                        FROM inventory_details
                        JOIN inspection_details ON inventory_details.bridge_id = inspection_details.bridge_id
                        JOIN testing_details ON inspection_details.bridge_id = testing_details.bridge_id
                        JOIN repair_details ON testing_details.bridge_id = repair_details.'$bridge_id'";
```

Comment: This join is the correct????????????

Comment: There are a few spaces where there should be none, e.g. repair_details. transaction_datetime, you shoud remove them. And you should put your passed bridge_id in the WHERE-clause.

Comment: what is the issue you face when you run this query ?